# QGIS 1.7 + MacOS 10.6 : georeferencing from map canvas bugs

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing

I am experiencing issues with the gdal plugin to georeference a raster. It works fine when I enter the coordinates manually but it does not work when I try to link the plugin with the map canvas.

Does anyone had this issue and was able to solve it?

Thanks

Guillaume

QGIS 1.7 MacOS 10.6.7

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug of the OSX version. It seems to work when the georeferencer window is docked ( http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2011-August/013164.html).

Bug report: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3743